# How to Use ifelse Statements in R

Tags: r

Here is my code and it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
nmesRAW <- read.csv("nmesUNPROC.csv")
nmesRAW$beltuse <- ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 1, ‘Rarely’, ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 2 ‘Sometimes’, ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 3 ‘Always’)))
```

Comment: Hello Andrew and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, could you add some data as example(you could use dput). From what I see, your code lacks of the else condition in last sentence ìfelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 3, "Always", "Put text otherwise")... but it will help us to help you if expected result is provided.

Comment: Could you show me how to properly do this nested ifelse statement? I don't know how to copy my data but basically its a column that displays either a 1 2 or 3 and I want to translate each number respectively to a word that correlates to that number. so 1 would be rarely, 2 would be sometimes and 3 would be always.

Comment: What do you mean by isn't working? Please be specific. Do you get an error? (what is the error?), does it give you incorrect results or something else. By the way you have missing commas after `ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 2` and `ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 3` so if you are using the code as it is in your actual code this will definitely not work.

Comment: I get this error: Error: unexpected input in "nmesRAW$beltuse <- ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 1, ‘"

Comment: I want to replace all 1's with rarely, all 2's with sometimes, and all 3's with always in this column. how do i do that?

Comment: You're also missing the `no=` argument of your last inner-most `ifelse`. I think two alternatives for this in base R would be a vector index (`c("Ra","So","Al")[nmesRAW$beltuse]`) or `sapply(nmesRAW$beltuse,switch,"Ra","So","Al")`.

Comment: I'm new to R, so how would I implement that into code? in order to sucessfully change the data

Comment: @Andrew look at the answer I've posted. Hope it helps. Welcome to R programming and StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to replace all 1's with rarely, all 2's with sometimes, and all 3's with always in this column. how do i do that?

This is how you would do it on your data, using `switch()`:

```
nmesRAW$beltuse <- sapply(nmesRAW$beltuse, function(x) switch(x, "1"="Rarely", "2"="Sometimes", "3"="Always"))
```

With some code example for reproducibility:

```
# some random data
nmesRAW <- c(1,3,1,2,3,3)
sapply(nmesRAW, function(x) switch(x, "1"="Rarely", "2"="Sometimes", "3"="Always"))
# output:
[1] "Rarely"    "Always"    "Rarely"    "Sometimes" "Always"    "Always"
```

### Using `ifelse()` only

If you insist on using `ifelse()` and nothing else (I hope this is not a schoolwork assignment), then your code should look like this:

```
nmesRAW$beltuse <- ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 1, 'Rarely', ifelse(nmesRAW$beltuse == 2, 'Sometimes', 'Always'))
```

The reason your code is giving you these errors is because you're missing a comma in your second nested if-else and also an 'else' statement in your third nested if-else.

As you can see, it is a bit all over the place when you nest an if-else this way and can quickly get out of hand.

When you do an `ifelse`, you will always need:

- the `test`, the condition to test against.
- the `yes` condition
- the `no` condition

The syntax looks like this `ifelse(x$var>10, "Large", "Small")`. When you nest your ifelse the way you did it, you quickly lose sight of that, and hence the missing commas, and the missing `no` condition in your last `ifelse`.

Comment: I have a large data set, beltuse is just one column and it has either a 1, 2, or 3. I want to change just that column so that if it is a 1 it says rarely, if it is a 2 it says sometimes, and if it is a 3 it says always. When I tried it your way it just changes the whole dataset to consist of just rarely always and sometimes in every column. The name of the one and only column I want  to change is called nmesRAW$beltuse

Comment: `nmesRAW$beltuse <- sapply(nmesRAW$beltuse, function(x) switch(x, "1"="Rarely", "2"="Sometimes", "3"="Always"))` this changes only the beltuse column